Black screen when logging in via Microsoft Remote Desktop on Ubuntu 24
This is really annoying me. Initially, this worked. Now it doesn't, and I've not been able to figure out why. While I can log in, etc., I just get a black screen. I've checked that I can actually log in (on the remote machine), but I get nothing in the MRD, which is getting very annoying.
I did even try with KDE, which I got working with VNC. But TBH I don't get on with KDE that much.
I like GNOME, is there anything anyone can suggest?
Additional information:

I did try xrdp.
Should I simply not log on to the remote machine?


Are you locally logged in to the remote Ubuntu desktop? If so, are you using the Default Gnome Desktop Sharing, or Default Gnome Desktop login, of have you installed xrdp in the remote Ubuntu Desktop? Edit your question and add these information.

xrdp works differently from Windows RDP. If you are locally logged in to the Ubuntu desktop, you won't be able to access that session remotely using xrdp. You will have to log out locally and then login remotely. See this answer  and this answer for more.

In the new Microsoft RDP Client (now called Windows App), you need to change the settings in the RDP file.
Find the line that says: use redirection server name:i:0
Change it to: use redirection server name:i:1
If you can't find the RDP file, you can create a new one:
Right-click on your current connection.
Select "Export" to save the file.
Open the saved file and make the changes mentioned above.
Import the edited file as a new connection.
Shout out to: Reddit Answer from @JohnDoeMan79

Seems to be an incompatibility with the 'modern' remote desktop app and windows app
use mstsc.exe if you are on windows, it will work (at least does on my machine)
